# come around sth or come around to sth

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct:
"If you come around that CD, could you buy it for me?"
"If you come around to that CD, could you buy it for me?"

Comment: It rather depends on what you mean.  It could be that the speaker’s friend knows you want a particular CD (perhaps as a joint ‘thank you’ gift for someone) but your friend disagrees with your idea.  In that case, you might say “If you come around to the CD... “. Because (in British English) to come around to something (it must be “TO”) means to change one’s mind about one’s previous objection to something.  If, as I suspect, you mean “If you FIND the CD, you should use the verb phrase “to come ACROSS”.  Could you clarify your question by editing it, please?

Answer (score 1):

Neither, I think you're trying to say "if you come across".

*To come across something: to find something or someone by chance: He came across some old love letters.*

To come around has a different meaning, You can come around someone's idea, meaning, you started to agree with that person's idea.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is **come across**. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/come_across) has

> Meet or find by chance.

With the example

> *Sometimes acquaintances tip him off about such books and at other times he comes across them by chance.*

So you can say

> If you come **across** that CD, could you buy it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Neither is correct, at least as far as normal speech goes.  A native speaker (at least an American one) would say "If you come across that CD..." - meaning if you happen to see it, even though you aren't specifically searching for it.